# Ambiguity Error

Tags: c#, linq

This is my code

```
 HotelMGT _DB = new HotelMGT();

    public virtual ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.TypeID = new string[] { "Assets", "Liabilities", "Income","Expenses" };
        var model = from r in _DB.AccountHead
                    orderby r.AccountHeadID ascending
                    //where r.AccountTypeID == AccountTypeID || (AccountTypeID==null)
                    select r; //_DB.AccountType;
        return View(model );
    }
```

and I got the following error.

```
 Ambiguity between 'MyHotel.Models.HotelMGT.AccountHead' and   
 'MyHotel.Models.HotelMGT.AccountHead'
```

Id the error relating to C# or MVC and how do I fix this? All suggestion is welcome.

Regards.

Comment: This would suggest that you have two classes with the same name in same namespace, and I't wouldn't compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comparing the same values so specify the table from which your getting the data.

The error is actually saying your comparing an egg with an egg but you only have 1 egg, we need the other egg.

Comment: I have look through and found nothing here is the entire page.

Comment: That's not what the error message says. And why should it be illegal compare something with itself?